# Gemfile 内のソースコードのメソッドの探し方について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, devise

devise gem の authenticate_user がなぜか正常なアカウントに対して 401 を出すようになったので
ソースコードにデバッグを挟んでどこのどの値がおかしいのかしらべようとしたんですが
devise のリポジトリ内でこのメソッドを検索しても定義場所が見当たりません

[authenticate_user! の検索結果](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/search?q=authenticate_user%21&unscoped_q=authenticate_user%21)

helper メソッドのようなので

[app/helpers/devise_helper.rb](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb)
もみてみたんですがメソッドは見当たりません

```
require 'devise'

authenticate_user!
```

と書いたときに呼ばれるコードはどうやって gem のリポジトリから探せばいいのでしょうか…

---

/usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb に

```
            def authenticate_#{group_name}!(favourite=nil, opts={})
              unless #{group_name}_signed_in?
                mappings = #{mappings}
                mappings.unshift mappings.delete(favourite.to_sym) if favourite
                mappings.each do |mapping|
                  opts[:scope] = mapping
                  warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
                end
              end
            end

            def #{group_name}_signed_in?
              #{mappings}.any? do |mapping|
                warden.authenticate?(scope: mapping)
              end
            end
```

というそれらしいコードを見つけたので

```
            def #{group_name}_signed_in?
              puts '======================================='
              puts mappings
              #{mappings}.any? do |mapping|
                puts mapping
                puts warden.authenticate?(scope: mapping)
                warden.authenticate?(scope: mapping)
              end
            end
```

とデバッグメッセージをみたのですが
コントローラから user_signed_in? をよんで
Rails を再起動し直して何も表示されません
ここではないんでしょうか…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

おっしゃるとおり、`authenticate_user!`は動的に定義されているメソッドなので単にgrepしても見つけるのは難しいです。

動的に定義されているメソッドに限らないですが、メソッドの定義位置を探すのにはpry-railsが役に立ちます。
https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails
Gemfileにpry-railsを追加した上で、適当なコントローラーのメソッドに`binding.pry`と書いてみてください。書くところは`authenticate_user!`メソッドが使えるところであればどこでもokです。

```rb
# users_controller の new actionを書き換える例
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # ↓を追記
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

そうするとrails serverのプロセスがそこで停止してpryが起動して、デバッグを開始できます。

```
[1] pry(#<UserController>)>
```

ここで、`$ メソッド名` と入力すると、そのメソッドの定義位置が表示されます。
`authenticate_user!`を入れると次のようになると思います。

```
[1] pry(#<UserController>)> $ authenticate_user!
From: /path/to/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:116:
Owner: Devise::Controllers::Helpers
Visibility: public
Signature: authenticate_user!(opts=?)
Number of lines: 4

def authenticate_#{mapping}!(opts={})
  opts[:scope] = :#{mapping}
  warden.authenticate!(opts) if !devise_controller? || opts.delete(:force)
end
```

これを見ると`/path/to/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:116`で定義されていることが分かります。

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/v4.7.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L116-L119

Comment: before_action の中にはかけないんでしょうか。

before_action -> {
    binding.pry
  }

と書いても特に止まったりしないです

Comment: 理由はわからないんですが2回起動し直したら pry モードに移行できました！　ありがとうございます

Answer (score 1):

以下のコマンドでgemのパスを探せます

```
$ gem which devise
```

Gemfileに`devise`のバージョンが書かれているはずなので、そのバージョンを参照してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！　これはこれで有用な情報なんですが、今回はディレクトリのパスは分かってい流のですが、膨大なデバイスのソースコードのどこに該当のメソッドの処理が書かれているかが知りたいです。トップの devise.rb がインポートしてる全ファイルをとても読みきれないのでメソッド名で検索したんですがヒットしなかったので質問した次第です